# creating a new multi tenant app which authorization and permissions system

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, authorization, cancan

I am writing a new authorization system and permission system for my multi tenant rails 3 app.

I need to have guests, basic users, site owners, site owners can have users, multi site owners with users and also admin users.

I am wondering what everyone would use for this setup ?
Devise, Authlogic, Sorcery etc ?
Canacan, declarative_authorization etc ?
or any other gems that would fit better for this sort of system.

thanks a lot
Rick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally prefer devise with cancan. I have yet to find anything that I was not able to do with that combination.